Differentiating between Passive verb and link verb plus adjective
Introduction
Get-passive is another way of passive construction. 'Get' instead of 'be' verb.

The window got (is) broken.

All passive voices should have an agent which can be omitted.
So, The window got broken (by the kid).
Important: Get-passives cannot be used for state verbs.
Nothing is known about the missing child. -correct (known -state verb)
Nothing gets known about the missing child - wrong

With that information my question:

They are getting married. Or They got married.


They are getting engaged.

Are 'married' and 'engaged' adjectives OR are they passive sentences? (get passive)
If they are 'get passive' formations, I would think they can be written as:
"They are getting married (by Father Carmelo/somebody.)" (I've never heard such a sentence).
Similar Get-passive sentences:

The window got broken (by the kid).
He got fired by his HR manager even though his technical manager defended him.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This is a case where you might have to learn by example when you can use got. I would argue that They got married and He got fired are verb + adjective rather than a passive verb, but I can't point you to a source to validate it.
Fortunately, it looks like you can choose to not use "got" and always be correct.
Practically speaking, however, in American English, "were married" or "were engaged" would be considered very formal. You will almost always hear "got married" and "got engaged."
Here's an example of why I say that "got" is verb + adjective:
You can say "The window got broken." For example:
Q: What happened yesterday?
A: The window got broken.
That's OK. Verb + adjective.
If you said:
A: The window was broken
The listener would probably be waiting for you to say by whom. (passive)
But in reality, you probably wouldn't say "The window was broken." Instead, you would say, "Someone broke the window." and avoid the passive altogether.
What you shouldn't say, but what you will hear quite often in the South, is "The window got broke."

I have upvoted your answer. I would appreciate your thoughts on my update. Thanks!

Would you say: They got married BY a minister? I would not. They were married by a minister. But: He got fired [by his boss] is clearly a verb.

@Lambie - For me, it comes down to formal/informal. I would say "They got married by a minister." But I would probably write "They were married by a minister." The latter being more formal than the former.

@BumbleBee - Your comment was "We mostly mention marriage, divorce, and engagement this way rather than using the 'be' verb." But I don't think that's necessarily the case. For example, "He's married." or  "She is divorced."

I updated my answer based on the "window got/was broken" example. Maybe I should just delete it, though, because this is a really difficult one to nail down!

If you accept "They got married by a minister", you would logically have to accept: A minister got them married. Would you? And also, the window was broken by x, is very common.

@swmcdonnell: She is married and she is divorced has not been discussed by us. There, 'is' is a link verb and "married' is a predicate adjective.  'get' is used for sentences like "They got married last week" or John and Mary got married last week.

The Passive Voice with 'Get'.
OP's query:

With that information my question:
1.They are getting married. Or They got married.
2.They are getting engaged.
Are 'married' and 'engaged' adjectives OR are they passive sentences? (get passive)

The get-passive has two structures:
get + adjective and
get + past participle.
I. Is "marry and get married" a transitive verb?.
If the sentence is passive, the verb should be transitive (should have an object).
As per Cambridge dictionary both"married someone" and "got married to someone" have the same meaning and can be used interchangeably. Both are passive sentences.(below Cambridge dictionary and MetaAI explanation at the end ).
Ref. Cambridge dictionary

We use to, not with, after get married + direct object and be married + direct object:
She got married to someone she met at college.
She’s married to someone she met at college.

"A got married to B" is clearly passive voice.
II. Is the verb ,"engaged" transitive?.
The verb "engaged" also has a transitive meaning.
Consider.
"I cleared the interview and I am getting engaged by the restaurant to wash dishes.".
*However being "engaged" in OP's sentence (to get married) is an adjective.".

engaged adjective..
having agreed to marry somebody.
When did you get engaged?
an engaged couple.
engaged to somebody.
She's engaged to Peter.
They are engaged to be married (= to each other).
She was engaged to marry the heir to the Spanish throne.

III. Active voice or Passive voice.
Hence, we can conclude:
1."A got married to B Or A married B" both sentences have the same meaning and are passive.
2."They are getting engaged." is active voice.
Edit 1:.
Looking at the arguments in the comments, I am quoting BBC learning English.
Get married can be passive -
bbc.co.uk.
Active:The man next door married me.
Passive : I got married to the man next door..
Consider the following sentences.
1.They got married
2.I got married to the man next door.
In the first sentence, it is not clear whether the action is done by the object (priest or minister).
So the confusion whether it is active voice or passive voice.
But the second sentence is clearly passive because the action is done by "the man next door".
MetaAI has given the same explanation. Please note that we can make a passive voice using 'at’ , ‘to’, ‘with’, ‘in’, instead of ‘by’. The following is a MetaAI explanation for the second sentence's passivity.AI**.
I got married to the man next door. Is it active or passive voice ?
Meta AI answered;

The sentence "I got married to the man next door" is in the passive voice.
.
In passive voice, the subject (I) receives the action described by the verb (got married). The doer of the action is the person who married me.
.
If you wanted to write it in active voice, you could say:
.
"I married the man next door" (this implies that you took action to marry him).
"The man next door married me" (this specifies who took action to marry you).
.
But note that "I got married" is a common and idiomatic way to express the idea, and it's not necessarily "wrong" to use the passive voice in this case!

I hope all the doubts expressed in the comments are clarified.
https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv112.shtml#:~:text=If%20you%20marry%20someone%2C%20that,a%20range%20of%20common%20expressions

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I did some research on this and this is my update:
Scenario 1
marry = get-marry = enter into a marriage or become husband and wife.
The above sentence DOES NOT mean "they were married," which is the usual passive. ('get' is a substitution for 'be' in Get-passives. That does not apply here."  Another possibility is 'married' is an adjective past participle (like "they got sad/surprised").
Quote from BBC: "I married the man next door = I got married to the man next door..."
So now, we cannot say "They got married last week by the priest." Because "they" are performing the action which is 'entering into marriage. If it was a passive sentence, the priest should have performed the action.
So, in this scenario, married has to be an adjective past participle and the sentence is ACTIVE.
Scenario 2
marry = perform the ceremony of marriage
Suppose get is a substitute for 'be' like in the sentence:
"My car got stolen yesterday,"
AND,
married = perform the ceremony of marriage,

Priest married them (active, priest performed the ceremony of marriage).

Changing to passive, we get:

They were married by the priest.

Substituting 'Get' for 'be" we get:

They got married by the priest.

Omitting the agent we get:

They got married.

Similarly,

John and Mary got married (by the priest) last week.   Or
John and Mary got married last week (omitting the agent).

Here got-married is in passive voice.
BUT
This scenario will not work when we write sentences like John married Mary last week. There, 'marry' has to have a different meaning which is "they entered into marriage or became husband and wife."
PS: Interestingly, the Cambridge website has 'get-marry' classified as passive without any syntax explanations.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/get-passive. This is clubbed along with "his car got stolen" and such examples where the active voice is clear. Active: The thief stole his car.
So, probably different sources give different meanings to marry and get-married.
So for specific sentences, we can write active/passive based on the meaning assigned to the verb "marry," and "get-marry."
I would appreciate your thoughts.
Thanks!
BumbleBee

NO: John and Mary got married (by the priest) last week. John and Mary were married by the priest. got married cannot be passive in standard English, which I assume is what you're after. to be married by a person. Much of your answer is inaccurate. Also, where's your proof (like you said to me, a native speaker who just knows this)

Your answer is misleading and wrong. Your statement: "Also, you get married, not by a person. However, You are married by a minister or public official." So a minister is NOT a person?  The other answer was helpful. I would expect some experts to comment on this.

The Cambridge example is this: They had only known each other for six months when they got married in Las Vegas. Sure, but not they got married in Las Vegas by [someone].

You still have not understood: To be married by [someone] and NOT: to get married by [someone]. Your examples are wrong. Since you refuse to listen, it's impossible to explain it to you...And yes, you are married by a person.  That is correct and so is my answer. :)

Scenario 1 marry = get-marry . No. The phrase is: get married.

marry and engage are not like break and fire. In any event, to get engaged can never be passive. You can't get engaged "by a person".
A passive requires an agent in order to see whether it is a passive:
He was/got fired (by his manager).
The window was broken (by the kid).
Those are transitive verbs.
They were married (by a preacher).
They got/were engaged by a person. [NO]
They got engaged, they became engaged. get=became, stative verb
You can't get engaged "by a person" (except for your services: we were engaged by the lawyer to do an investigation). You are engaged, become engaged or get engaged (informal, mostly speech).
Also, you get married, not by a person. However, You are married by a minister or public official.
You can say: I got married yesterday. I'm getting married today. Again, no by. My brother, a minister, is marrying us today. We were married by him. Marry can be transitive like that. Engage cannot.
get married is NOT a get passive. It means to become married.
GET plus an adjective:
get married, get rich, get old, get lazy are all adjectival.
Finally: If you think get married is a passive verb in "They got married by a priest", then, logically, you would have to accept its active form: A priest got married us. which of course is absurd.
The active voice is this: A priest married them.
The passive voice is this: They were married by a priest.

Do you have any source to justify your argument? What I have read is they are get-passive. "In married by him," marry is not transitive. by is a preposition. Also you state: 'Also, you get married, not by a person. However, You are married by a minister or public official." So a minister is NOT a person?

@BumbleBee What argument? That passives require agents, either stated or implied?  That's very basic. They are being married by Father Carmelo. To be married by someone.

So, what is your stance? Is it an adjective or a get-passive?

@BumbleBee get married by someone is not idiomatic in standard speech.

Yeah. I have already mentioned in my question that I have never heard it that way and that is why I ask. I have added an introduction.

@BumbleBee It's not fair to change the question after asking it. What you are not getting is that get in the window "got broken" means became. You took my stuff and incorporated it  into your question.

I have NOT 'changed the question.' I have added an introduction so that people would not repeat my doubts.

@BumbleBee Yes,  you added something I said: All passive voices should have an agent which can be omitted. So, The window got broken (by the kid). That was not there in the first iteration. Only you said it could be omitted.  I meant to test a sentence for passivity, you have to be able to add the agent.
